# Render image without saving

Tags: python, django

I want to get an image from user, work with it at beckend and render result back to user. Is it possible to do without saving image on disk?

my view:

```
class InputImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()


def get_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = request.FILES['image']
            #some actions with image
            return render_to_response('results.html', {'image': image})
        else:
           form = InputImageForm()
    else:
        raise Http404
```

In template, tag {{ image }} returns a name of file.

Comment: I don't think it is possible if you want to show it to the user it need to be somewhere. You may save the file temporary save it via an imagehosting api and delete the current image in your server for example. to render the image of template  img src="{{image.url}}"

Comment: Its already somewhere if we can work wit it) django cache.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that returning a page to the user would normally involve two requests: one for the HTML page, and one for the image itself as referenced by an img tag in that HTML. But as you say, without storing it anywhere in the meantime, the image would be lost.

There is an alternative: you can use a [data uri](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to include the actual data for the image inline in the html. That means you won't have to persist it across requests, as everything will be returned at one. Data uris are supported in most browsers, including ie8+.

You can format the data like this, for example:

```
from base64 import b64encode

encoded = b64encode(img_data)
mime = "image/jpeg"
uri = "data:%s;base64,%s" % (mime, encoded)
```

And use it directly in the template:

```
<img src="{{ uri }}">
```

Comment: Nice solution! But I got "must be convertible to a buffer, not InMemoryUploadedFile" error, can you help with it, please?)

Comment: @Harkonnen You need to set `img_data = form.cleaned_data['image'].file.read()`.

Comment: The solution doesn't work for me. It just shows the broken image logo, even though I followed the steps exactly. Ok, got it: I had to add `encoded = encoded.decode('ascii')``

Answer (score 4):

This answer is inspired by @Daniel Roseman answer

write the image to `BytesIO()`

```
from PIL import Image  
img = Image.open("image.jpg") 
data = io.BytesIO()
img.save(data, "JPEG") # just an example, load the image into BytesIO any way you like.
```

encode `img` into `base64`

```
encoded_img = base64.b64encode(data.getvalue())
```

decode `img` in context, as well as setting `content_type`

```
decoded_img = encoded_img.decode('utf-8')
img_data = f"data:image/jpeg;base64,{decoded_img}"
```

render your template

```
return render(request, "index.html", img_data=img_data)
```

in your HTML template

`<img src="{{ img_data }}" >`

you can check also https://buraksenol.medium.com/pass-images-to-html-without-saving-them-as-files-using-python-flask-b055f29908a

Answer (score 3):

If your form is Model Form .then jus try the below code.

```
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

class InputImageForm(forms.Form):
    image = forms.ImageField()
    class Meta:
       model = YourModel



def get_image(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = InputImageForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            image = request.FILES['image']
            save_image_from_url(form,image)

        else:
           form = InputImageForm()
    else:
        raise Http404



def save_image_from_url(model, img):
    r = request.FILES['image']

    img_temp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
    img_temp.write(r.content)
    img_temp.flush()

    i = model.image.save("image.jpg", File(img_temp), save=True)
    return HttpResponse(i.read(), mimetype="YOUR MIME TYPE")
```