# Save image file to Django Upon Submit Using CreateView CBV

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

Yesterday, using this solution [View an Image Using Django CreateView Before Submitting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57064354/view-an-image-using-django-createview-before-submitting) I was able to figure out how to display an image when a user clicks on the choose file button in my Django project.  However, I can't figure out how to now save the image when the user submits the form.  I realize the solution I am using is leveraging the HTML URL to display the image using Javascript.

When I am using an approach for the use to attach an image and then submit the form without displaying the image first, this works fine.  However, when I use the solution referenced above, it is not capturing the image.

This works...

```
<div>
  <h2>Photo: </h2>
</div>

<div>
  {{ form.image }}
</div>
```

However, when I try to leverage this instead....from the prior solution...

```
<input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" />
<img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />
```

And using Javascript...

```
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#blah')
          .attr('src', e.target.result)
          .width(150)
          .height(200);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

The file displays, but I can't figure out how to save it to the database upon user submit.

I tried to use various solutions documented here...[Django: add image in an ImageField from image url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393202/django-add-image-in-an-imagefield-from-image-url) But no luck so far.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And it turned out to be so simple!!!  It's simple when you know the answer BTW..

```
<input type='file' name="django_form_field_name" onchange="readURL(this);" />
```

Making sure the input name matched the django form name was the way to get the image URL into the database with the proper location.